# Loops in dot2tex. Or easely draw complex graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, dot2tex, dot2texi

**My original question :**

Is it possible to use loops in dot2tex?

I would like to type something like:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage[pgf]{dot2texi}

\begin{document}

\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]
digraph G {
\foreach \x / \y in {0/1,1/2,2/3}
a\x -> a\y [label = "b_{\x,\y}"]

}
\end{dot2tex}


\end{document}
```

Instead of:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage[pgf]{dot2texi}

\begin{document}

\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]
digraph G {
a0 -> a1 [label = "b_{0,1}"]
a1 -> a2 [label = "b_{1,2}"]
a2 -> a3 [label = "b_{2,3}"]

}
\end{dot2tex}


\end{document}
```

Thank you. Note that this is a toy example, I have several (complicated) cases where I could use loops.

**EDIT**
What I get from the comment it's that it is impossible.

What I'm actually looking for is something that allow me to draw complex graph (I don't want to manage positioning of nodes as in tikz) and to use loops to define the graph (there are some regularity and it could save me a lot of typing).

If you know such tool/packages please tell me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think the dot language handles TikZ loops: you have to look for the correct dot syntax, or to create your script with another tool.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks for your answer. Do you know any convenient tools?

Comment: @wece The `dot2tex` environment writes the contents verbatim to an auxiliary file, without any interpretation.

Comment: @egreg Ok thanks. But is there something "similar" that would allow loops?

Answer (score 3):

I get the same output files with the following `test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage[pgf]{dot2texi}

\newtoks\dtttoks

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\global\dtttoks={}
\foreach \x / \y in {0/1,1/2,2/3}{
  \edef\temp{a\x\space -> a\y\space [label = "b_{\x,\y}"]}
  \global\dtttoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\dtttoks\temp^^J}
}
\edef\BODY{digraph G {^^J\the\dtttoks}}
\def\start{\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]}
\expandafter\start\BODY
\end{dot2tex}
\endgroup

\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]
digraph G {
a0 -> a1 [label = "b_{0,1}"]
a1 -> a2 [label = "b_{1,2}"]
a2 -> a3 [label = "b_{2,3}"]
}
\end{dot2tex}


\end{document}
```

Both files `test-dot2tex-fig1.dot` and `test-dot2tex-fig2.dot` contain

```
digraph G {
a0 -> a1 [label = "b_{0,1}"]
a1 -> a2 [label = "b_{1,2}"]
a2 -> a3 [label = "b_{2,3}"]
}
```

Not really practical, I guess.

Comment: Wow ... looks like it work :) But sorry I don't understand half of what is in there ... Could you please explain a bit so that I can try to generalize for my cases? Thanks a lot

Comment: @wece Maybe you could add one of your more complex cases.

Comment: Actually I don't have any in full. I have the formal definitions and I want to draw them to have a "visual" of what it looks like. Most of the definitions are like: for all nodes q in graph G there are 6 nodes q1 q2 q3 .. q6 in graph G' and for all edges of type ... there are several edges of a different type in G'. That's why I try to find something to use loops while drawing